# How to load a sklearn model in Tensorflowjs?

Tags: scikit-learn, tensorflow.js

I have a gradient boost model saved in the .pkl format. I have to load this model in tensorflowjs. i can see that there is a way to load a keras model but I can't find a way to load a sklearn model. Is it possible to do this?

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to load sklearn model in tensorflow.js. Tensorflow.js allows to load models written in tensorflow.

Though, I haven't tried myself, but I think that you can possibly use the [scikit learn wrapper](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/wrappers/scikit_learn) to rewrite the classifier in tensorflow. The model can be saved and converted to a format that can be loaded in tensorflow.js.