# Load sklearn model in scikit.js

Tags: scikit-learn, scikit.js

Is it possible to load a sklearn pipeline saved as a pickle file in scikit.js?  I could't find anything related in the documentation.
I am basically trying to make a model that will run in javascript without needing a backend server like node.js etc.

Comment: This [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59881163/how-to-load-a-sklearn-model-in-tensorflowjs) might give you some idea.